# Get "Cannot read property 'x' " in nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a quiz game using JavaScript.

I stored the question and answer destination in a nested array.

In a format like this

```
var questions = [
    ["QUESTION",
    "CHOICE_1", "CHOICE_2","CHOICE_3",
    "DEST_1", "DEST_2", "DEST_3"]
]
```

When I get the question name I will use like `questions[n][0]` and for first choice destination `questions[0][4]`

But in some situation, it returns as `Cannot read property 'x'` I want to know what cause this and how to fix this. Thanks

```js
        $('.quiz').hide();
        $('.result').hide();

        var questions = [

          //1
          ["Click either button",
            "Yes", "No", "",
            "2", "2", ""],

          //2
          ["You will have an error when clicking the third button",
            "FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD",
            "3", "3", ""],

          //3
          ["If it works it should show you this page",
            "END OF ERROR DEMONSTRATION", "CLICK THIS WILL ALSO CRASH", "",
            "", "", ""],
        ];

        function start() {
          $('.start').hide('400');
          $('.quiz').show();
          getQuestion(1);
        }

        function getQuestion(n) {
          var n = n - 1;
          var d1 = questions[n][4];
          var d2 = questions[n][5];
          var d3 = questions[n][6];
          
          $('#d_txt').html(questions[n][0]);
          $('#c1').html(questions[n][1]);
          $('#c2').html(questions[n][2]);
          
          //Hide choice 3 if not exist
          if (questions[n][3] == "") {
            $('#c3').hide();
          } else {
            $('#c3').show();
            $('#c3').html(questions[n][3]);
          }
          $("#c1").click(function () { getQuestion(d1) });
          $("#c2").click(function () { getQuestion(d2) });
          $("#c3").click(function () { getQuestion(d3) });
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<body style="background-color: #E9ECEF">
 <div class="jumbotron start">
  <h1 class="display-5">Simple JS Quiz</h1>
  <p class="lead">Click start amd I will guide you through how this is error</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" href="#" role="button" onClick="start()">Start!</a>
 </div>

 <div class="jumbotron quiz">
  <h1 class="display-5">Question</h1>
  <p class="lead"><span id="d_txt">DETAIL_TEXT</span></p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" id="c1" href="#" role="button">CHOICE_1_TEXT</a>
  <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" id="c2" href="#" role="button">CHOICE_2_TEXT</a>
  <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" id="c3" href="#" role="button">CHOICE_3_TEXT</a>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add the code to the question itself, not a link to an external page. You can use Stack Snippets to get a debugging environment (the icon looks like a page with `<>` in it).

Comment: I suggest looking at using objects rather than the nested array.

Comment: It's likely that either the first index you're looking for or the second one are out of range. Please provide the code you're using to get the array data, otherwise we will not be able to properly help you. Besides, an object-based approach is likely better in this situation, rather than an array-based one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added Stack's snippet instead of StackBlitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the snippet provided, whenever a click action is performed on either of `THIRD`, `END OF ERROR DEMONSTRATION`, `CLICK THIS WILL ALSO CRASH` - correspondingly the destination value (say `d`) is set to `""` and `getQuestion(d)` gets called. Thereafter, `getQuestion` evals as follows:

```
var n = n - 1;                // evals to var n = "" - 1 => undefined
var d1 = questions[n][4];     // evals to var d1 = questions[undefined][4]
```

Thus resulting in error: `Cannot read property '4' of undefined`

Hope that helps. Also, as mentioned in the other comments too, it's recommended to use object-based approach rather than nested arrays for such scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But can you explain more about `object-based approach`?

Comment: For getting started, you may refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects